# Why random() result doesn't have the type inferred?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to follow the [guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/guide.html#generating-a-secret-number), and am compiling the following code:

```
use std::rand;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    let secret_number = (rand::random() % 100i) + 1i;

    println!("The secret number is: {}", secret_number);
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
➜  guess git:(master) ✗ cargo run 
   Compiling guess v0.0.1 (file:///home/mkpankov/rust/guide/guess)
/home/mkpankov/rust/guide/guess/src/main.rs:6:26: 6:40 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
/home/mkpankov/rust/guide/guess/src/main.rs:6     let secret_number = (rand::random() % 100i) + 1i;
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `guess`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I looked at definition of `%`, turns out it uses [`Rem` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/ops/trait.Rem.html). And the trait defines the operator only on same-typed operands.

Now, I use `100i` as second operand, and that should be `int`, according to [reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/reference.html#integer-literals).

So, why can't compiler infer the proper type requested from `random()`, as the manual suggests? (and my Haskell experience hints it should).

Not fully sure it's a bug, hence the question.

Some additional info:

```
➜  guess git:(master) ✗ rustc --version
rustc 0.12.0-nightly (63fe80e1f 2014-10-08 23:42:39 +0000)
```

Runs on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

**Update:** I noticed this error is intended to happen (the guide tells the way to fix it later). However, the original question of why can't the compiler infer the type still applies.

Comment: This is very interesting... Note that if you interchange the order of the arguments (i.e. `100i % rand::random()`) it will inference the type correctly. I am curious about this behavior too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer why the compiler can't infer the type is simple. This is `Rem` definition:

```
pub trait Rem<RHS, Result> {
    fn rem(&self, rhs: &RHS) -> Result;
}
```

Note that it takes two type parameter, `RHS` and `Result`. Each trait also has implicit type parameter called `Self`, which designates the type for which the trait is implemented. This is how `Rem` implementation for `int` looks like:

```
impl Rem<int, int> for int { ... }
```

So here `Self = int`, `RHS = int` and `Result = int`. But traits are open, that is, you can implement foreign trait for any type you own and you can implement your own trait for any foreign type. No one can prevent you for adding an implementation like this one (`Self = X`, `RHS = int`, `Result = int`):

```
struct X;

impl Rem<int, int> for X {
    fn rem(&self, arg: &int) -> int { *arg }
}
```

And now `rand::random()` invocation is ambiguous: should the type checker select `rand::random::<X>()` or `rand::random::<int>()`?

Note that in theory the type checker could decide to use the only type which is applicable in this case. However, this would lead to very fragile programs. Suppose that this is the case and the original program compiles normally. In the same module, but in an unrelated part, you use some other type, say, `X`, which is imported from another library. And then the author of this library suddenly decides that it would be nice if `X` implemented `Rem<int, int>`. Because importing a type also imports all trait implementations for that type, then BAM, you program suddenly stops compiling.

It may be fine if it is your program. After all, you can always notice such compilation error and correct it accordingly. However, suppose that this happens not in your program but in a library you depend on. For example, if `liby` used `X` from `libx`, and then `libx` author decided to add an offending trait implementation for `X`, then `liby` suddenly stops compiling and there is nothing *you* can do. This would mean, for example, that you won't be able to modify library versions easily.

Comment: But why can't it select `int` specialization, when there's no foreign trait implementations? All it has to consider is built-in trait implementations, of which only one matches.

Comment: Because this would make your program very fragile. Imagine that you import some type from another library. All is fine, you use it in completely unrelated part of the module. And then the upstream author decides that it is a good idea to implement `Rem<int, int>` for this type. Because importing types also means importing all trait implementations for that types, your program will suddenly stop compiling. It may be ok if it is your program, but what if it is another library which you don't control but also depend on? It is much safer to just forbid such kind of inference.